# SQL - How to insert a subquery into a query in order to retrieve unique values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, subquery, reportbuilder3.0

I am writing reports using Report Builder 3, and I need some help with an sql query to get unique values.

Using the following sample data:

[image]

I need to be able to get one single value for feeBudRec returned for each feeRef. The value of each feeBudRec is always the same for each individual feeRef (eg for every data row for feeRef LR01 will have a feeBudRec of 1177).

The reason why I need to get a single feeBudRec value for each feeRef is that I need to be able to total the feeBudRec value for each feeRef in a feePin (eg for feePin LEE, I need to total the feeBudRec values for LR01 and PS01, which should be 1177 + 1957 to get a total of 3134; but if I don't have unique values for feeBudRec, it will add the values for each row, which would bring back a total of 11756 for the 8 LEE rows).

My experience with writing SQL queries is very limited, but from searching the internet, it looks like I'll need to put in a subquery into my SQL query in order to get a single unique feeBudRec figure for each feeRef, and that a subquery that gets a minimum feeBudRec value for each feeRef should work for me.

Based on examples I've found, I think the following subquery should work:

```
SELECT a.feeRef, a.feeBudRec
  FROM (
    SELECT uvw_EarnerInfo.feeRef, Min(uvw_EarnerInfo.feeBudRec) as AvailableTime
    FROM uvw_EarnerInfo
    GROUP BY
    uvw_EarnerInfo.feeRef
) as x INNER JOIN uvw_EarnerInfo as a ON a.feeRef = x.feeRef AND a.feeBudRec = x.AvailableTime;
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to insert that subquery into the query I'm using to produce the report (as follows):

```
SELECT
  uvw_EarnerInfo.feeRef
  ,uvw_EarnerInfo.PersonName
  ,uvw_EarnerInfo.PersonSurname
  ,uvw_EarnerInfo.feePin
  ,uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeDate
  ,uvw_RB_TimeLedger.matRef
  ,uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeTypeCode
  ,uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeCharge
  ,uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeElapsed
  ,uvw_WoffTimeByTime.WoffMins
  ,uvw_WoffTimeByTime.WoffCharge
  ,uvw_EarnerInfo.feeBudRec
  ,uvw_EarnerInfo.personOccupation
FROM
  uvw_RB_TimeLedger
  LEFT OUTER JOIN uvw_WoffTimeByTime
    ON uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeId = uvw_WoffTimeByTime.TimeId
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN uvw_EarnerInfo
    ON uvw_EarnerInfo.feeRef = uvw_RB_TimeLedger.feeRef
WHERE
  uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeDate >= @TimeDate
  AND uvw_RB_TimeLedger.TimeDate <= @TimeDate2
```

If that subquery will get the correct results, can anyone please help me with inserting it into my report query. Otherwise, can anyone let me know what I will need to do to get a unique feeBudRec value for each feeRef?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the exact schema, but assuming the uvw_EarnerInfo lists the Pin, Ref, and Rec without duplicates, try adding an extra column (after personOccupation) on the end of your query such as :

```
feeBudRecSum = (Select SUM(FeeBudRec) From uvw_EarnerInfo x 
            where x.feePin = uvw_EarnerInfo.feePin
            Group By x.FeePin)
```

Note that you would not Sum these values in your report. This column should have the total you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The key to Report Builder is to get your query correct from the offset and let the wizard then structure your report for you. It takes all the hard work out of structuring your report manually.
I haven't used Report Builder for a while now but in the query builder of the report displaying the graphical representation of your query you should be able to drag and drop columns in and out of the query set. Dragging a column upwards and out of the box (showing your columns) would have the effect of causing your report to break on this column. 
If you restructure this way you will probably have to run the report generator again to regenerate the report and restructure it.
Once you are happy with the structure you can then begin to add the summary columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned that I have used Report Builder quite a lot before, but I have just never had to get out unique values like this for a report before. Unfortunately, this is not a matter of formatting the report correctly. If I put the feeBudRec column on the left of the break (ie, as a Group, not part of the details of the report) and try to sum the values of feeBudRec for the feePin I get the same incorrect results (adding up a feeBudRec value for each row of data for each feeRef) as I do if the feeBudRec field is part of the details.